# How to make WordPress menu items?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am learning WordPress and basically I have this very simple site, I have the following header file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php  language_attributes(); ?> >
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php  bloginfo('charset');   ?>">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title><?php bloginfo('name');  ?></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

        <?php  wp_head(); ?>

    </head>
    <body <?php  body_class(); ?>>

    <header class="site-header">
        <h1><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"></a><?php bloginfo('name');  ?></h1>
        <h5><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h5>

        <nav class="site-nav">
            
            <?php  
                $args = array( 
                    'theme_location' => 'primary' 
                );
            ?>    

            <?php  wp_nav_menu($args); ?>

        </nav>

    </header>
```

Now I believe, the menu is actually created by the below line of code:

```
        <?php  wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
```

Now when I check in the Front End, i.e. I load my site, I see that the only item in my menu is "sample-page", I was following from 1:38 onwards **[HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AShql_Ap1Yo&list=PLpcSpRrAaOaqMA4RdhSnnNcaqOVpX7qi5&index=4&nohtml5=False)** and you'll see how this guy get a menu with "about us", "home", "contact" etc…

Now why am I not getting the same and how can I create those menus?

Answer (score 1):

To create your own menu, you need to first go to your wp-admin dashboard. Then go to Appearance/menus.

[image: Go to Appearance/menus]

Here you can create your own menus, or modify existing menus. After you do this, choose the role of the menu from the near footer of the page, just before the "Save menu" option. [image: Set the locations for the menu.]

And I hope you're all done!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is attaching the 'primary' theme location to wp_nav_menu. Go to your dashboard Appearance>Menu page and see if you have a Primary menu in 
the dropdown next to 'Select a menu to edit'. If so, select it. The pages in that menu should show. You can add to them as needed.